# How to use <> expression in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We need to convert following query to Entity framework syntax based query but not fond any alternative for '<>' condition:

**Query:**

```
        select (FirstName+' '+LastName) AS Name ,WorksNumber from [TSHumanResource] 
    join [TSUserProfile] on [TSUserProfile].[TSPersonID] = [TSHumanResource].[TSPersonID] 
    join [TSPerson] on [TSPerson].[TSPersonID] = [TSHumanResource].[TSPersonID] 
    where [TSUserProfile].[TSUserStatusID] = 1 
and [EmployeeReference] <> ' ' and [MMSUserID] is not null order by [WorksNumber] asc
```

Here's what I was tring:

```
        (from HR in oDB.TSHumanResources
         join UP in oDB.TSUserProfiles on HR.TSPersonID equals UP.TSPersonID
         join P in oDB.TSPersons on HR.TSPersonID equals P.TSPersonID
         where UP.TSUserStatusID == 1 && HR.EmployeeReference <>
         select new
         {
             ID = e.TSPersonID ,
             ID = e.TID,
         }).Take(10);
```

Comment: Have you want to use LINQ to Entities? Try using `!=` operator for checking inequality either in lambda or query expression.

Comment: The SQL Server operator `<>` means not equal. In c#, the not equal operator is written like this: `!=`.

Comment: You do realize that the joins you are `tringing` are inner joins, not left joins, don't you?

Comment: OK, let me get this straight. You manage to convert a SQL statement into LINQ, where `=` becomes `equals`, `AND` becomes `&&`, etc. and then you don't know what to do with `<>`? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server operator [`<>` means not equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional). In c#, the not equal operator is written like this: [`!=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/not-equal-operator).

You have another problem in your linq query - you are currently doing an [inner join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join) instead of a [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#left-outer-join).

A left join in LINQ is a bit cumbersome comparing to a left join in SQL - it has to go through a group join first. Your query should look more like this:

```
from hr in TSHumanResource
join up in TSUserProfile on hr.TSPersonID equals up.TSPersonID into upgroup
from upg in upgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join p in TSPerson on upg.TSPersonID equals p.TSPersonID into pgroup
from puphr in pgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where up.TSUserStatusID = 1 
&& HR.EmployeeReference != " " // Assuming you want it different than a single space
// Other conditions here - I don't know where MMSUserID belongs to
order by hr.WorksNumber // just guessing here - I don't know if it's from hr
```